# Сокрытие белой рамки, если не установлен flash

Tags: html, javascript, css

Как сделать так, чтобы люди, у которых не установлен flash, не видели белую рамку flash-объекта на странице. Для них нужно сделать так, чтобы они даже не догадывались о том, что на странице чего-то не хватает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<object>you don't have flashplayer</object>
```

Comment: Что-то я не врубился...
Мне надо, чтобы пользователи без Flash не видели флеш-рисунок, а видели все, что дальше по сценарию страницы. Не должно быть надписей, типа "УСТАНОВИТЕ ФЛЕШ ПЛЕЕР" и т.д.
Просто, если есть флеш-плеер - будет рисунок, если нет - то рисунка как будто бы и не было никогда...
Как это сделать. У меня PHP

Comment: Тогда просто

    <object></object>

если браузеру флеш неизвестен, он просто проигнорирует тег, сочтя его за обычный пустой блок, а если поддержка флеша имеется, то браузер распарсит все свойства в object и вставит саму флешку.

Comment: не получается ну никак... как не пробовал - ничего не выходит... Начинаю приходить к выводу, что у меня установлен какой-то странный IE....